# How to use ApplicationManager to load an object with out GAC'ing it?

Tags: c#, .net, cassini, assembly-resolution, applicationmanager

I'm trying to use the Cassini webserver to create a deployment test host- a sort of embedded web server to isolate web server config issues from app deployment issues. Okay, so this line of code blows up until I put Cassini in the GAC:

```
 // physical path points to the bin folder with the dll
_host = (Host)_appManager.CreateObject(appId, typeof(Host),
                                   _virtualPath, _physicalPath, 
                                   false /*failIfExists*/);
```

The above fails with FileNotFoundException -- as if it is trying to find the Cassini.dll

Should I just be able to tell [ApplicationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationmanager.aspx) where to look without taking the extreme step of putting it into the GAC?

I am using Cassini 2.1 and the [source code is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2006/03/09/548131.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I had a similar problem and what I needed to do was put the searched-for DLLs into a bin subdirectory.

If the searched-for DLLs are located in the current directory, it's enough to create a junction point called "bin" that refers to the current directory.

Comment: That was it. Cassini launched from in c:\foo\bin, so for casinni to load itself (a class in it's own assembly) again without gac, it had to load from c:\foo\bin\bin